# Determine whether a Facebook post is public or private from the id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

My app uses the Facebook dialog sharer and whenever users share one of my links Facebook gives me back the `post_id` on the redirect page.

Right now, I'm logging the the post_ids to make sure that the posts went through correctly. The problem is, I can't see the posts for most of the shares because of the user's privacy settings.

So, how can I determine whether a post is private or public if I have the `post_id`? Which api can I refer to and is this even possible?

Comment: You can use the privacy-field on the post. More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/post .

May I ask why you want to know?

Comment: I basically only want to log the publicly available posts. I don't want to waste time logging post_ids if I won't be able to check them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you request the Post (with your App Access Token) like

```
GET /{post_id}
```

and get nothing in return, then you can be sure that the Post is non-public. If it is non-public, you'll also not be able to request the privacy field.

If you're having an User Access Token with `read_stream` permission in the moment the User is sharing something, you can use this Access Token to request the Post. Then you should also be able to see the `privacy` field.